# OSB Design questions

Tags: email, osb, oracle-service-bus

I have to implement a system to poll emails from a mail server.
Process the email contents(body, subject, sender, date, etc) and prepare a request to send to another service using these data.
My question is: using OSB and the email transport I can read the variables(body, subject, etc), then I have to split the subject into 3 different variables(It's coming in this format: Var1) and prepare a call to another service(this service is already deployed and its wsdl and Url are known).
How can I do all of this? How can I split the subject and prepare my request? Do I have to use a java class or OSB can do it automatically?

How can I achieve this? Are there better options?

Comment: What is the criteria to split the subject? It is very easy to do like I said in my response to another question of yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mail transport is a polling based approach. And you need to setup a Proxy Service to poll your mails from a mail server. In you Proxy Service, you process your subject and body. Whether you need a custom Java class depends on how much you work with XML.

The more XML your message is, the less likely you need Java. If you are familiar with XQuery/XSLT, you can also in many ways avoid using custom Java to process your messages.

Once you have your messages ready for delivery, you can route them to a business service which may or may not be WSDL based.